# jquery mobile prefetch/cache images

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am writing a a phonegap app, and just wondering if there are anyway to prefetch images but not to prefetch a whole page, or if i cache some dynamic images from php server and then use the images later.

What I am just trying to do, is to load the images before it is displayed so to save some loading time, if the data speed is slow.

Wondering if there are anyways to prefetch images without doing the `href="prefetchThisPage.html"` data-prefetch as it prefetch the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

follow the instructions on the following link.

https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js

there are 3 requirements for cordova, read the instructions and there will be another link for those.